# A simple method of mathematical formula representation for jaccard

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

There are some doubts about using Jaccard formula, such as Wikipedia's explanation. The following should be

```
jaccard_score([0 1 1], [1 1 1])
0.6666666666666666
```

According to the Jaccard formula, the calculation method is
`intersection / (size of A + size of B - intersection)`. So, it should be `2/(3+3-2) = 2/4 = 0.5`.

But obviously this is not the case. Can anyone give a direct formula calculation method to get this 0.66666666?

Comment: Why should the result be 0.66666?

Comment: print(jaccard_score(y_true[0], y_pred[0]))  The result of my running on pycharm is 0.66666

Comment: So by looking at the code of `jaccard_score`, can't you see which calculation it uses?

Comment: Actually, I did step into the code of jaccard_score , but it is not intuitive and difficult to understand @mkrieger1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interpreting the formula incorrectly; "size of A" refers to the *cardinality* of the set.  The data [0, 1, 1] is a boolean representation of a set A  in which the universe consists of three elements, and the value '1' indicates which element (from the universe) is in the set A.  So the "size of A", where A is represented by [0, 1, 1], is 2.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is such that:
intersection/(sum/size of A + sum/size of B - intersection)
Which in your case is:

```
2/(2 + 3 - 2) = 0.666
```

You are taking the size of A to be the length of the elements, whereas it is the sum. Similarly, for B just that your mistake got overlapped because the length and sum are same.